# Union in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, union

The following is my query

```
 Select vehicleID from trip where (StartingDate between ''+ convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,111) +'' and ''+ convert(varchar(10), @EndDate,111)+'')
or (enddate between ''+ convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,111) +'' and ''+ convert(varchar(10), @EndDate,111)+'')
or(StartingDate <= @StartDate and enddate >= @EndDate)
UNION
Select vehicleID from VehicleMaintenance where (FromDate between ''+ convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,111) +'' and ''+ convert(varchar(10), @EndDate,111)+'')
or (todate between ''+ convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,111) +'' and ''+ convert(varchar(10), @EndDate,111)+'')
or (FromDate <= @StartDate and todate >= @EndDate)
) as vehicle
```

how to select distinct vehicleId from the above query result....

Comment: Hmmm... using a union statment should only return the distinct records, is part of the query missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `UNION` will remove duplicates (whereas `UNION ALL` will not), so you should already have unique vehicle ID's